# How To Put Tree Panel in Viewport in EXT JS 4

Tags: extjs4

This My Code, but only the tree panel is displayed(please help me):

> Ext.define('User', {
>           extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
>           fields: ['name']
>       });
>
> ```
> var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
>     height: 300,
>     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
>     width: 300,       region: 'east',
>     columns: [
>         {dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1, header: 'Tree Panel', xtype: 'treecolumn'}
>     ],
>     store: {
>         model: 'User',
>         root: {
>             name: 'Rumah',
>             children: [
>                 {name: 'Gavin Renaldi', children: [{name: 'Benar Sekali', age: 2, children: []}]},
>                 {name: 'Gavin Ripharbowo', children: []}
>             ]
>         }
>     },
>     viewConfig: {
>         plugins: {
>             ddGroup: 'user-dd',
>             ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> Ext.onReady(function () {
>
> Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
>       layout: 'border',
>       items: [{
>           region: 'north',
>           html: 'Page Title',
>           autoHeight: true,
>           border: false,        width:100,      height:100,
>           margins: '0 0 5 0'
>
> ```
> }, {
>     region: 'west',
>     collapsible: false,
>     html: '<h1 class="x-panel-header">Page Title</h1>',
>     title: 'Navigation',
>     width: 150,       height:100,         items:'tree'
>
>     // could use a TreePanel or AccordionLayout for navigational items
> }, {
>     region: 'center',
>     xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
>     activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
>     items: [{
>         title: 'First Tab',
>         html: 'For A While',
>     },{           title: 'Second Tab',            html : 'The Second Tab Content'         }]
> }] }) })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

```
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
```

Just get rid of this line in the tree definition, and add it normally to the viewport. For example:

```
{
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
    activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
    items: tree
}
```

(You might have to add the renderTo to the viewport definition)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i have solved the problem by inserting the treepanel to the viewport

Answer (score 0):

by this, i can insert treepanel to viewport

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> <Getting Started Example </title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="resources/css/ext-all.css" />

    <script src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"> </script>
    <script src="ext-all-debug.js"> </script>
    <script src="/src/tree/Panel.js"> </script>
    <script src="/src/windows/Window.js"> </script>
    <script src="/src/panel/Panel.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="reorder.js"></script>

  <script>
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['name']
    });

    var tpanel = new Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        height: 100,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 200,
        region: 'west',
        columns: [
            {dataIndex: 'name', flex: 1, header: 'Tree Panel', xtype: 'treecolumn'}
        ],
        store: {
            model: 'User',
            root: {
                name: 'Rumah',
                children: [
                    {name: 'Gavin Renaldi', children: [{name: 'Benar Sekali', age: 2, children: []}]},
                    {name: 'Gavin Ripharbowo', children: []}
                ]
            }
        },
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ddGroup: 'user-dd',
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
            }
        }
    });
Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        region: 'north',
        html: '<h1 class="x-panel-header">Page Title</h1>',
        autoHeight: true,
        border: false,
        width:100,
        height:100,
        margins: '0 0 5 0'

    }, tpanel, {
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
        activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
        items: [{
            title: 'First Tab',
            html: 'The first tab\'s content. Others may be added dynamically',
        },{
            title: 'Second Tab',
            html : 'Tab berfungsi untuk sdfkjdf'
        }]
    }]
});

})

</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
```